# IOS4 - Send data using UDP socket on Wifi

Tags: networking, ios4, asyncsocket

I am trying to send data using the AsyncUDPSocket class. And I can send data using the iPhone simulator over the wire to another machine that is running a simple C-coded listening server. I can also receive data over the wire using a client connected to the simulator(server). However, when I tried the same over Wifi, using the simulator, I could only send data but not receive any data.

I read on another post, that unicast data makes this possible. How can I acheive this using AsyncUDPSocket?

Thanks,
Angelo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out. A newbie kind of thing, really.

When I set my Mac network preferences to Ethernet, I get an IP for me to communicate. However, when I turn Airport(Wi-Fi for more newbies) ON, and ethernet cable disconnected, I checked my network preferences, and sure enough my IP address was a different one.

Spoke to a friend (an ace in networking) and the thing clicked immediately: On WiFi networks a DHCP server allocates an IP address. This IP address has to be reserved, at the very least, at the DHCP server. Since my IP was not reserved, I had to change the IP address, in my udp_client.c file, recompile and run the client to connect.

BTW, I can now communicate between my iPhone and my PC using my local WiFi (office) network.

For any who might face the same problem, do not be assured that the IP address of your mchine is the same, when you switch from LAN to Wifi, and use the device mostly for WiFi reated testing. :)